# RoR: How to show/print data from other model on a table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a table called "Notes" and a dropdown in _form.html.erb for a list of subjects from a model called subject which works.

```
<div class="field">
    <%= f.label :subject, class: 'dropdown' %>
      <div class="dropdown">
      <div class="field">

        <%= f.collection_select(:id, Subject.all, :id, :subject) %>

  </div>
```

The problem is I can not get it to print either to "show" or the "table" and I am wondering how to do this?

Notes index view:

```
<tbody>
    <% @notes.each do |note| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= note.created_at.localtime %></td>
        <td><%= note.updated_at.localtime %></td>
        <td><%= note.user_id %></td>
        <td><%= note.user.full_name %></td>
        <td><%= note.user.email %></td>
        <td><%= note.studentname %></td>
        **<td><%= note.subject.subject %></td>**
        <td><%= note.grievance %></td>
        <td><%= note.penalty %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', note, class: 'btn btn-primary btn-xs' %></td>
```

I know I have to define the subject model in the notes_controller. I have been trying to do this with no success.

```
  def subject
    @subject = Subject.all
  end
```

Subject schema

```
create_table "subjects", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "subject"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end
```

All I am trying to do is to get the option selected in the subject dropdown, populated from the subject model, to show/print on the notes table. I'm a newbie at rails. Would really appreciate any help and will provide more code if needed. Thanks!

Comment: I am not sure what are you willing to achieve but, defining action `subject` doesn't do you any good, probably the assignment should be done in `show` action.

Comment: Thanks, I have a drop down options menu with a list of subjects populated from a subjects table and I want to print the option the user selects to the notes table as above. I tried your suggestion but I still get undefined method `subject' for nil:NilClass

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are looking for a "has_one" Active Record Association.  In order for you to be able to call `note.subject` you need to have this association set up.  Here is what it would look like from the http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html.

```
class Notes < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :subject
end
```

You also need a database migration that looks something like this:

```
class AddUserToUploads < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_reference :subjects, :notes, index: true
  end
end
```

This is the option if you actually want a subjects model.  If you are simply trying to only allow certain inputs (via your dropdown) and don't need your subjects to actually be a model you might want to look at enums:
http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html.  In that case, you simply need to declare an enum within your Notes model (model/notes.rb) which looks like this:

```
 enum subject: [ :none, :math, :science, :history, ...etc ]
```

This allows you to call:

```
<%= f.select :subject, options_for_select(Notes.subject_array) %>
```

where `subject_array` is a method declared in your Notes model which looks like this:

```
def subject_array
  a = Notes.subjects.map do |k,v|
    [k.humanize, k]
  end
  return a
end
```

This returns all of your subjects decaled in your enum in a reader friendly way (with spaces in place of underscores, etc.)  Enums can be tricky, but are a nice way to generate a defined list of possible values for a model attribute (such as note subjects in your case).  This way you don't even need a model for subjects.

Comment: wow! Thanks, I actually got it working now in my convoluted way above but your post is great advice too for the future! I really appreciate that.   FWIW I took advice above and did <%= f.collection_select(:subject_type, Subject.all, :subject, :subject) %> and it works

Answer (score 0):

```
 <%= f.collection_select(:subjectid, Subject.all, :id, :subject) %>
```

should contain a name as the first parameter.In the controller method that selects @notes this value can be used to select the particular notes for that subject.

```
@notes = Note.find_by_subjectid(:subjectid)
```

Hope this helps if not please be a little more specific in your question

Comment: ok thanks very much, I have some success with your suggestion. Only problem now is it is printing the subject id rather than the name but at least something is being printed.